# Using class name to trap .click() event

Tags: ajax, popup

My ajax code is not catching the .click event with following type of code wherein I trying to trap the .click event using view_data.

```
<div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Need to Pud ID and Name of Work here..What the....</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body" id="workstatustable"> 
                    <input type="button" name="AMWP/2017-18/1" value="AMWP/2017-18/1" id="AMWP/HQTC/2017-18/1" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data">
                    <input type="button" name="AMWP/2017-18/2" value="AMWP/2017-18/2" id="AMWP/HQTC/2017-18/2" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data">
                    <input type="button" name="AMWP/2017-18/3" value="AMWP/2017-18/3" id="AMWP/HQTC/2017-18/3" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data">                   
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Update Status</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
    </div>
```

my ajax code is as follows:-

```
$('.view_data').click(function(){  
                var modwork_id = $(this).attr("id");  
                $('#show_modid').html($(this).attr("id")); 
                fetchModal();
            });

function fetchModal() {
                 var modwork_id = $("#show_modid").html();
                 window.alert($("#show_modid").html());
                $('#viewstatus_Modal').modal("show"); 
                $.ajax({      
                    url:"workstatus.php",   
                    method:"POST",      
                    data:{modwork_id:modwork_id},   
                    success:function(data){     
                         $('#workstatustable').html(data);      
                         $('#viewstatus_Modal').modal("show"); 
                    }   
                });
            };
```

The issue is the modal window is not popping up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got It... I have relocated the position of the ajax() and its cool....

```
function fetchModal() {
                 var modwork_id = $("#show_modid").html();
                 window.alert($("#show_modid").html());
                $('#viewstatus_Modal').modal("show"); 
                $.ajax({      
                    url:"workstatus.php",   
                    method:"POST",      
                    data:{modwork_id:modwork_id},   
                    success:function(data){     
                         $('#workstatustable').html(data);      
                         $('#viewstatus_Modal').modal("show"); 
                         $('.view_data').click(function(){  
                             var modwork_id = $(this).attr("id");  
                             $('#show_modid').html($(this).attr("id")); 
                            fetchModal();
                         });
                        }   
                });
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in here.

you didn't declare the class properly as u write in ajax is .view_data and #show_modid

you have to do this >>

```
    class="modal view_data fade "
```

so you can use ".view_data" in your ajax.
and do this >>

```
    "#dataModal"
```

in your ajax

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for responding. But the problem seems somewhere else. The Modal is coming up sometimes only and that too when I right click and use Inspect Element mode. In this also, the Inspect Element window should have occupied large part of the screen only then Modal Window Popsup.

Answer (score 0):

I got the soulution to the problem. I was trying to attach a function() to HTML item before the item/element was declared or found on the page. I inserted the ajax() call in the Success: clause. The plan is now working. Thanks.